# QGIS Couldn't load plugin XY due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am using QGIS 3.26. (on Windows 10) and have run into problems when trying to install a couple of plugins, namely AniMove, Cluster Analysis and Cluster Map. These all return error messages when trying to install, below is the example for Cluster Analysis:

> Couldn't load plugin 'Cluster-Analysis-plugin-main' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 423, in *startPlugin
> plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
> File "C:\Users/imand/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Cluster-Analysis-plugin-main_*init**.py", line 35, in classFactory
> from .cluster_analysis import ClusteringMain
> File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
> File "C:\Users/imand/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Cluster-Analysis-plugin-main\cluster_analysis.py", line 32, in
> from .cluster_analysis_dialog import ClusteringMainDialog
> File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
> File "C:\Users/imand/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Cluster-Analysis-plugin-main\cluster_analysis_dialog.py", line 35, in
> from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler
> File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

> Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
> QGIS version: 3.26.0-Buenos Aires Buenos Aires, 0aece2818e
> Python Path:
> C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python
> C:/Users/imand/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
> C:/Users/imand/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
> C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
> C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.26.0\bin\python39.zip
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\DLLs
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib
> C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.26.0\bin
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
> C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
> C:/Users/imand/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python

I have tried looking up this error, but none of the provided solutions have worked for me (including a hard reinstall). I'm not versed in Python.

Comment: Install `sklearn` package using OSGeo Shell. `pip install scikit-learn`

Comment: That worked, thank you!!